# FuzzyLookup in BIML

Tags: ssis, biml

I'm trying to do the following in BIML:

[image: FuzzyLookup Columns tab]

I'm at a bit of a loss on how to do this in BIML. Here is what I've tried:

```
    <FuzzyLookup 
        Name="Fuzzy Lookup" 
        ConnectionName="WO7" 
        Exhaustive="true"  
        AutoPassThroughInputColumns="true"
        >
      <ExternalReferenceTableInput Table="map.AgencyWO7" />
      <Inputs>
        <Column SourceColumn="AgencyName" TargetColumn="AgencyName" />
      </Inputs>
      <Outputs>
        <Column SourceColumn="AgencyId" TargetColumn="AgencyIdWO7" />
        <Column SourceColumn="AgencyName" TargetColumn="AgencyNameWO7" />
      </Outputs>
```

The result is the following error:

> (-1,-1) : Error 5 : The input column  for the
>   Fuzzy Lookup Fuzzy Lookup references external column  that cannot be found in the reference table. Verify that the
>   input mapping references a valid column in the reference table.
>   Property TargetColumn. EmitSsis. There were errors during compilation.
>   See compiler output for more information.

Comment: Maybe you can find an example of code here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21755311/416988

Answer (score 0):

I think you are maybe missing a reference to the previous transform which is effectively the joining arrow, had you been using SSDT.
Also the format I use to set passthrough = true is on a per column basis.

```
<FuzzyLookup Name="Fuzzy Lookup" MatchIndexName="" ConnectionName="WO7">
   <InputPath OutputPathName="[Previous Transform Name].Output" />
   <ExternalReferenceTableInput Table="map.AgencyWO7" />
   <Inputs>
       <Column MinSimilarity="85" MatchTypeExact="true" PassThrough="true" SourceColumn="AgencyName" TargetColumn="AgencyName" />
   </Inputs>
   <Outputs>
       <Column SourceColumn="AgencyId" TargetColumn="AgencyIdWO7" />
       <Column SourceColumn="AgencyName" TargetColumn="AgencyNameWO7" />
   </Outputs>
</FuzzyLookup>
```

Try the above code, and if all else fails you can design the fuzzy look up in SSDT and then import it into biml using **Mist/BimlStudio** which is pretty reliable.

https://varigence.com/Mist

Cheers